# get CWD where process was started

Tags: linux, process

I have a program called `/usr/bin/myprogram.x`

In one shell window I did something like

```
cd /run001/
myprogram.x &
cd /run/009/
my program.x &
cd /run/234/
myprogram.x &
```

I kicked off a total of around 10 jobs, all under various directories, is there a way to find those run directories ?

If I do a `ps -ef | grep myprogram.x` it reports them all as `/usr/bin/myprogram.x` however I am looking for the directory each was kicked off under.  Is there a way to find that?

Answer (score 0):

Just find their process ids (with `ps`) and in `/proc/<PID>/` should be a link called `cwd` which points to the directory where process has stared.

Comment: Or with `pgrep`, which may be safer.